# Create Pdf from visualforce page with button

Tags: visualforce, pdf, getcontentaspdf

I create a PDF with button at the account record. That works good, but now I want to pass information from the account record into my visual force. I tried it, see below, but the (AName) account name does not appear at the pdf.

**APEX CLASS**

```
public class attachPDFToAccount2 {

private Id accId {get; set;}
Public List<Account> AccList {get; set;}
public String AName {get; set;}

public attachPDFToAccount2() {
    accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    AccList = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId]; 
    FOR (Account Acc : AccList) {
        AName = Acc.Name;
    }
}

public final Account a;

public attachPDFToAccount2(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
    a = (Account)standardPageController.getRecord(); 
}

public PageReference attachPDF() {
    
    PageReference pdfPage2 = Page.pdfpage2; 
    Blob pdfBlob; 
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { 
        pdfBlob = pdfPage2.getContent(); 
    } else { 
        pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('...');
    }
    Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'pdffile.pdf', body = pdfBlob); 
    insert attach;
    
    PageReference pageWhereWeWantToGo = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view();
    pageWhereWeWantToGo.setRedirect(true); 
    return pageWhereWeWantToGo; 
}

}
```

**ACTION PAGE**

```
<apex:page action="{!attachPDF}" extensions="attachPDFToAccount2" standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:detail inlineEdit="true" relatedList="true"></apex:detail>
</apex:page>
```

**RENDER PAGE**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="attachPDFToAccount2">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.pdfStyle}"/>
<center>
    <h1>Visualforce PDF Sample - {!AName}</h1>
</center>
<table align="center" style="border: 1px solid #6699CC;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #6699CC; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 200%; padding: 10px;">NOTES</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>TEST</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PageReference pdfPage2 = Page.pdfpage2; 
...
pdfBlob = pdfPage2.getContent();
```

This causes a new, separate instance of the controller to be loaded; it doesn't know about the variables in the original context. You need to give it the correct parameter:

```
PageReference pdfPage2 = Page.pdfpage2; 
pdfPage2.getParameters().put('id', accId);
Blob pdfBlob; 
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { 
    pdfBlob = pdfPage2.getContent(); 
} else { 
    pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('...');
}
```

Comment: Can you give me some more tipps, I changed the code but I got no results, the accountname does not appear

Comment: @peXeq Did you solve your issue by now? I am facing similar problems, i.e. canno't create the PDF in the first place, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370089/render-visualforce-page-report-of-custom-object-to-pdf-and-create-attachment-via If you have further insights, help is very appreciated.