# Render VisualForce page report of custom object to PDF and create attachment via page detail button

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, attachment, pdf

I have a VisualForce page which shows a report of a custom object `MyCustomObject`.

I have two page detail buttons, one for "*Show report*" only showing the report rendered as PDF and one "*Attach report*" to render the report as PDF, and attach it to the object as PDF-attachment.

While the VisualForce page (launched via "*Show report*") is viewing my example PDF properly, opening the attached file (after clicking "*Attach report*") results in "Error. Failed to load PDF document." - expectable since the file seems to be empty-sized.

Following examples in https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IDp6QAG I created the following code

**VisualForce page MyCustomObjectReport**

Example VF page to represent the report PDF to be generated, viewable by "*Show report*" button

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="MyCustomObject__c">
    <h1>MyCustomObject report</h1>
    This is a report of the MyCustomObject report to be filled with further parameters.
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class MyCustomObjectAttachPdf**

Apex class with action code to generate PDF, attach it to current `MyCustomObject` object and redirect to current `MyCustomObject` object details page

```
public class MyCustomObjectAttachPdf {
    
    private final MyCustomObject__c obj;
    
    //constructor
    public MyCustomObjectAttachPdf(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        // instantiate object of current record
        obj = (MyCustomObject__c)standardPageController.getRecord();
    }
    
    //action method - returns a page reference
    public PageReference attachPDF() {        
        // Get PDF content from VF page
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.MyCustomObjectReport;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',obj.Id);
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
        
        // Create attachment and attach
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.Body = pdfBlob;
        attach.Name = 'MyCustomObjectReport.pdf';
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParentId = obj.Id;        
        attach.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
        insert attach; //insert the attachment
        
        // Redirect the user to object page
        PageReference destPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(obj).view();
        destPage.setRedirect(true);
        return destPage;
    }
}
```

**VisualForce page MyCustomObjectAttachPdf**

VF page triggered by "*Attach report*" button, calling `MyCustomObjectAttachPdf` apex class, hence generating pdf from `MyCustomObjectReport` VF and attaching it to the `MyCustomObject` object

```
<apex:page action="{!attachPDF}" extensions="MyCustomObjectAttachPdf" standardController="MyCustomObject__c">
</apex:page>
```

**Issue**

The VF page `MyCustomObjectReport` can be viewed via "*Show report*" button without any problems, showing the example PDF output.

Via the "*Attach report*" button, an action is happening and a file '*MyCustomObjectReport.pdf*' is attached to the `MyCustomObject` object and the details page is shown. The resulting *.pdf file however seems to be empty-sized and fails to open: "Error. Failed to load PDF document."

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Note: If I use `Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPdf();` instead of `getContent()` the resulting 'MyCustomObjectReport.pdf' is non-empty, but does not show the content defined in `MyCustomObjectReport`, just an empty document with a strange green top line elemen, but at least stating the correct name 'MyCustomObjectReport'.

Comment: 2nd Note: I already found https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350661/create-pdf-from-visualforce-page-with-button, but this seems to be an open issue too, although the reporter states having successfully created a PDF...

Comment: 3rd Note: I now found, that the content I get with `getContentAsPdf()` looks like the bottom part of the page if I directly access the report page via `https://<my-org>.lightning.force.com/apex/MyCustomObjectReport`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was active developer mode `User Settings > Advanced User Details > Developer Mode`, which seems to change the return-behaviour of the `getContentAsPdf()` function. After disabling this option the generated *.pdf file matched the PDF preview using my "*Show report*" button.

Additionally use `Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPdf();` rathern than `getContent()`, even if your VF page has the attribute `renderAs="pdf"` property.

Note that the protection mentioned in some other posts online DID NOT WORK for me to prevent this strange behaviour with development mode enabled.

```
Blob pdfBlob; //create a blob for the PDF content
if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { //if we are not in testing context
    pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent(); //generate the pdf blob
} else { //otherwise, we are in testing context and getContent() gets funky so create the blob manually
    pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('Some Text for a boring PDF file...');
}
```